# User input in Python is not being written to database

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

Just for fun, I'm creating a website in Python and using the Google Datastore to create a website that lets users post a movie title and a review for the movie. I am also using Jinja2 templating. The problem is, the `movie_name` gets written to the databases on all occasions except one, which is in the class that says `MoviePage`. It seems like that is the only class that isn't reading the variable `movie_name`, not even the jinja template is reading that variable. However, I have other variables in my html that are being parsed by jinja2, it's only that one variable I'm having trouble with. Here is my code:

```
    class MovieReviews(db.Model):
      movie_name = db.StringProperty()
      review = db.TextProperty(required = True)
      created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
      last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)

    class MoviesOnWebsite(db.Model):
      movie_name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
      created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add= True)



   class AddMovie(StrHandler):
      def get_front(self,movie_name="",error=""):
        add_movie = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MoviesOnWebsite")
        self.render("add-movie.html",movie_name=movie_name,error=error,add_movie=add_movie)

      def get(self):
        self.get_front()

      def post(self):
        haveError = False
        movie_name = self.request.get("movie_name")

        params = dict(movie_name=movie_name)

        if not movie_name:
          params['error_movie_name'] = "Must write movie name"
          haveError = True
        if haveError:
          self.render("add-movie.html", **params)
          self.response.out.write('You have errors')
        else:
          addmovie = MoviesOnWebsite(movie_name=movie_name)
          addmovie.put()
          site_url = urllib.urlencode(dict(movie_name=movie_name))
          self.redirect('/' + site_url)

    class MoviePage(StrHandler):
      def get_front(self, review="",error=""):
        addmovie = AddMovie()
        full_url = addmovie.site_url
        movie_reviews = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MovieReviews")
        self.render("movie_review_page.html", review=review,error=error,movie_reviews=movie_reviews)

      def get(self,url):
        self.get_front()

      def post(self,url):
        path = urlparse.urlparse(full_url).path
        movie_name = self.request.get('movie_name')
        review = self.request.get("review")

      if review:
        movie_rev = MovieReviews(path = path,review = review)
        movie_rev.put()

      else:
        error = "You haven't submitted a review"
        self.get_front(review,error)
```

And a small code snippet from my html page called `movie_review_page.html` to verify that the jinja syntax is correct:

```
<body>
  <h1>{{movie_name}}</h1>
....
```

I'll explain what my code is doing. The classes `MovieReviews` and `MoviesOnWebsite` are just database models. The class `AddMovie` lets a user add a movie to the database if no one has ever submitted a review for that particular movie. After the user adds the movie name to the database, they get redirected to a url that looks like this: `www.websitename.com/nameOfMovie`. And from there, the class `MoviePage` has a form that lets users add a movie title and a review and adds it to the database. The problem as I mentioned before, when a user adds a movie title and review in the `MoviePage` class, only the review gets written to the database and the movie title is blank. The movie title that I want written to the database is the movie the user is doing a review for, namely, the name of the movie found in the url. The `movie_name` only gets written to the database in the class `AddMovie`. And the url with the path that has the name of the movie also works. The problem is in the `MoviePage` class.  I should mention that `add-movie.html` has a textbox with the name `movie_name` and `movie_review_page.html` does not. If I change the variable from `movie_name = self.request.get('movie_name')` to `movie_name="abcd"` then abcd gets written to the database, but it doesn't work the other way around.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Which webframework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what web framework you are using but the issue seems to be caused by query parameters vs url paramters.

The other values are included in the form and therefor retrieved successfully from
`self.request.get`. For movie_name you can't use the same call, you will need to extract it from the current url somehow, but this will cause problems if your movie has non standard characters in it or spaces.

Rather url encode the parameter and include it in the redirect:

Change the redirect to this:

```
import urllib
self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(dict(movie_name=movie_name))
```

The generated url should look like `/?movie_name=The%20Terminator`

Then retrieve the data like so:

`self.request.get("movie_name")`

Comment: Hi Anarci, thank you for commenting. I'm using the webapp2 framework. That part of my code looks like this: `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+])+', MoviePage)], debug = True)` . I have a regex pattern following the path to take in any movie name that may consist of a combination of letters, numbers or symbols.

Comment: I see, I updated the answer with some code you can try

Comment: I replaced the `self.redirect` that I had used with the redirect using urllib provided, but I get a server error.

Comment: It says invalid syntax for `class MoviePage`. I haven't edited that portion of the code. I only added the new `self.redirect` in the last line of the `AddMovie` class.

Comment: its most likely an indent issue. Can you create a gist of the new code?

Comment: I edited the code above to reflect the changes. I fixed the syntax issue, it was just a missing parenthesis. I changed the url encoding into 2 separate statements: `site_url = urllib.urlencode(dict(movie_name=movie_name))` and then redirected to `site_url`. I did this so that I could use `site_url` in my movie page class. I try to call the variable in the `get_front` method of the `MoviePage` class but I get an error: `AddMovie object has no attribute site_url`. What I'm trying to do here is get the entire url, then extract the path from the url and post that to the database.

Comment: Hmm, if the redirect is done correctly it should already be contained in the url parameter. What about `print(urlparse.urlparse(url))` or `print(url)`. That should contain the movie name

Comment: The url is contained in the parameter. So now the url looks something like: `www.websitename.com/nameOfMovie = movietitlehere`. But now when I try to retrieve the movie name from the url (as seen in the edited code above) it still won't write to the database.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue and now the movie name is written to the database :) I changed two lines in the `MoviePage` class inside the post method. First I got the current url I was on. Then I retrieved the path from the url. Lastly since the url looks something like this: `www.websitename.com/nameOfMovie = movietitlehere`, I split the path string using the equal sign as a delimiter and put the result in the database. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient solution but it works for now. Thank you for all your help I truly appreciate it!